# Binding a domain to a webhost

Tags: domains, dns, godaddy, nameserver

I've bought a domain name from GoDaddy and I decided to host it on Ali Baba Cloud. I am abit new to that stuff so I'm wondering, what do I need to change beside the name servers? Any record I need to add? I've changed the name servers but no avail, it did not work.. Is it something to do with the records?

Comment: This is such a basic question that I feel like it should have a duplicate here with a great answer.   Darned if I can find it though.

Comment: It is a mistake to change NS records unless you really know what you are doing. Even then, it is still a bad idea. Why? Because it confuses people and creates a less stable scenario. I always recommend managing your DNS records with your registrar unless you absolutely require cPanel or other control panel to manage it for you. Are you using a control panel?

Comment: Well, I am using the Ali Baba's control panel to manage the webhost and the GoDaddy's panel to change the records. (if that's what you meant)

Comment: If you are still using the GoDaddy control panel for DNS, then you do not change the NS records. You change or add an A record to point your domain name to the Ali babba supplied IP address. Then, optionally, you would add a CNAME to point www.example.com to example.com.

Comment: I just contacted them and it seems they 'do not support' the IP thingy.. And I quote `Our web hosting doesn't have the public IP. You can use Cname in GoDaddy.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to log into your GoDaddy account and change the Name Servers(which you get from Ali).  If you tell us the domain name, we can check, but you can also do that yourself by looking at the Whois record and seeing which Name Servers appear:  http://whois.domaintools.com/

If they are showing on the record and your domain still isn't working/resolving, you need to go back to Ali Baba and see if there is anything else that needs to be done on their end.

Comment: I did that and contacted them as well and it seems to be working now, thank you.